# References to cells and worksheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem that I don't understand at all:

```
i = 150
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar").Cells(i, 3).Value Like "*:*" Then
  MsgBox "I found a colon!"
End If
```

As you might guess, the sheet foobar has at position (150, 3) a cell containing a colon, thus the message box is shown.

Now I want to do this:

```
i = 150
Cell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar").Cells(i, 3).Value 'fails right here
If Cell Like "*:*" Then
  MsgBox "I found a colon!"
End If
```

Here it gives me an error saying "Object variable or With block variable not set. In fact saying:

```
Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar")
```

gives a similar message. Why? What am I doing wrong? I just want a reference of that object, or at least a refence.

Comment: Please format your code the next time by using the `{ }` button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You might want to give more detail or code. When I run that code snippet against a test worksheet with a colon in that cell, I get no error and see the MsgBox.

Comment: Might I suggest you use Instr instead of Like since you are looking for a specific character. It will make your code easier to read since the intention will be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bottomline:**

- When handling **objects**, use `Set`.
- When handling **primitive** data (integers, longs, strings*, variants*) you do not use it.

`Sheet`, `Workbook`, `Range`, are objects. Therefore, you need to use `Set` when assigning them to variables.

A `Range.Value` returns a Variant (that can be a long, a string, etc.) So, you **cannot** use `Set`.

==========================

Now, about your error message... I'd say then that maybe before in your code, `Cell` **is being declared as object**. Try use another variable name, or check the Cell variable type.

To check this, right click on it and then click in 'Definition'. Have it declared as `Variant` might fix the problem (be aware of side effects it might cause, though).

==========================

*I know these types aren't 'primitive'; I used as an example here for the sake of explanation's cleanliness.

Comment: Strangely I don't think it is. I use it for range variables all the time :p For each cell in range just reads so nicely that I can't help but take advantage of it.

Comment: VBA strange behaviors.. hehe. I believe that *in his code*, VBA is interpreting Cell as a Excel Cell rather than a variable named Cell (otherwise I believe he wouldn't get that error). But as @PaulR said... further details are appreciated to understand better what's going on here.

Comment: I believe the Cells is reserved, but Cell seems to not be. Maybe *within his code*, Cell is previously declared as a object.

Comment: @Tiago: Yeah in my code x instead of Cell works. ;) And many thanks for your post!

Comment: Good to know, mate. These are the tricky problems Excel reserves for us... hehe.

Answer (score 2):

As your assigning an object the line

```
Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar")
```

should read

```
Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```
Cell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("foobar").Cells(i, 3).Value
```

you are trying to assign the value of cell (probably a string) to a cell. Take the `.Value` off and the assignment should work better. The Excel message you encountered is not the best: sometimes you get it when you assign variables of the wrong type.

However, the `If Cell Like` might not work. (Hint: the `.Value` has to get moved, not deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following code and it works probably in your code make sure the ActiveWorkBook is actually the Active Work book you want(if you are working with multiple work books)

```
Sub test()
i = 3
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value Like ":" Then
    MsgBox "I found a colon!"
Else
    MsgBox "didn't find a colon!"
End If

Cell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
'fails right here
If Cell Like ":" Then
    MsgBox "I found a colon!"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dim MyCell as Variant` (or as string) since Cell is an existing object